# Can't get button to delete Closes list item

Tags: javascript

i am in a bit of a pickle.

I am trying to get a button to delete its parent when clicked.

But when i run the code it won't respond. in fact , it doesn't delete anything at all.

I have specified that   `IF() event.target === deleteButton{ remove parent}`

but it either doesn't recognise the event, or it fails to find the parent.

a bit of help would be greatly apreciated!

I

```js
const todoListElement = document.getElementById('ordered-todo-list');
const form = document.getElementById('todo-form');


const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.delete');

todoListElement?.addEventListener("click", todoListEraser)

function todoListEraser( event:MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event.target)

    if (event.target === deleteButton ){
        (event.target as HTMLElement).closest('li')?.remove();
    }
else {
        return console.log('did not work, try again');
    }
}
```

```html
<template id="list-item-template">
    <li class="list-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="status-toggle" name="form-checkbox">
        <p class="task-text"></p>
        <button class="delete" >X</button>
    </li>
</template>

<ol id="ordered-todo-list">
</ol>
```

am working in typescript.

Comment: can you try `event.target.contains(deleteButton)` or `deleteButton.contains(event.target)`

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be completely wrong for what you need, but this doesn't seem to be your complete code so I had to take some guesses.

There are two ways I can see this being done. If the `<li>` elements in your template are added to the list ***before*** this JavaScript executes, you can use the first method (commented out). If the `<li>` elements from your template are added after this JavaScript executes, the second method should work just fine.

```js
/*
// Method 1
document.querySelectorAll(".delete").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  });
});
*/

// Method 2
document.querySelector("#ordered-todo-list").addEventListener("click", e=> {
  if(e.target.className.includes("delete")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<ol id="ordered-todo-list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <input type="checkbox" class="status-toggle" name="form-checkbox">
    <p class="task-text"></p>
    <button class="delete" >X</button>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <input type="checkbox" class="status-toggle" name="form-checkbox">
    <p class="task-text"></p>
    <button class="delete" >X</button>
  </li>
   <li class="list-item">
    <input type="checkbox" class="status-toggle" name="form-checkbox">
    <p class="task-text"></p>
    <button class="delete" >X</button>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Method 1** adds event listeners to the delete buttons themselves. Then it simply removes the `parentElement`.

**Method 2** adds the event listener to the `<ol>` element and checks to see if the element clicked (`e.target`) is a delete button by checking the `className` attribute.

Comment: Thanks so much! method 2 worked like a charm. i was indeed adding content through javascript. checking for a class with a name is such a usefull tool. i will defenitely be using that in the future.